# Why does TeamCity add "csproj.teamcity.patch" to web app package files?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I suspect there's probably an easy answer to this I'm just not seeing, but whenever I run a TeamCity build with either MSBuild or the Visual Studio solution runner against a .csproj and target "Package", the build artifacts always include the "csproj.teamcity.patch" string after the project name:

[image]

Running the same process via command line doesn't include these. The problem it's causing me is that my build script has a target which looks for "Web.deploy.cmd" after the package task runs and obviously it's not finding it when files are named this way. I'm reticent to change the command in the build script to include the TeamCity string as it will play havoc with running it from outside the build servers.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how you'd work around it when you need to be able to refer to the artifacts by name?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I can't turn off this behavior, created a config param called teamcity.msbuild.generateWrappingScript, set it to false, and still, the wrapping is happening. Note I am using nantcontrib's <msbuild/> task, not the native teamcity msbuild runner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may set 'teamcity.msbuild.generateWrappingScript' configuration parameter with value 'false' to make TeamCity avoid generating wrapping script.

TeamCity MSBuild/Solution build runners used to generate wrapping scripts to add TeamCity-provided tasks.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, that makes sense. Documentation for it is here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/MSBuild

Comment: In case anyone else is confused as I was, you need to add a parameter under the "Build Parameters" in TeamCity for the relevant project. On that page of your project's settings add a new parameter with a "Kind" of "Configuration parameter".